# Array of array of pointers

Tags: c++

I have a pointer `Particle*`.
What I want to create is a matrix in which each cell contains one of this pointer.
I tried:

```
Particle*** particles=(Particle***)malloc(1000);
Particle p0(0,0,0);
particles[0][0]=ps.AddParticle(p0);
```

but when I try the last instruction I got an error, because I think my program tries to write outside the memory allowed.

Sorry, but I'm actually not so good with C++.

Can anyone explain me how can I do this?

Comment: If you're not so good with C++, why are you going the hardest way? Try the STL containers first.

Comment: It honestly looks like you want (for simplicity) a `std::vector<std::vector<Particle>>`, or a more efficient class to replace the double vector. For starters as is, if `Particle` is at all "C++ish", `malloc` will mess things up.

Answer (score 2):

Use vector instead

```
#include <vector>
struct Particle
{
    Particle(int a_){a=a_;}
    int a;
};

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<vector<Particle*>> vPart;
    int nbLines=5;
    int nbColumns=10;
    for (int i=0;i<nbLines;++i)
    {
       vector<Particle*> vTmp(nbColumns,NULL);
       vPart.push_back(vTmp);
       for (int j=0;j<nbColumns;++j)
       {
           vPart[i][j]=new Particle(i*nbLines+j);
       }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Hope that helps,

Comment: Thanks, tried this, but when I try to assign:
    
    vPart[0][0]=ps.AddParticle();

I got this error:

Access violation writing location 0xcdcdcdcd.

Comment: I have added the full code with the particle code. If you follow this pattern it will work. What does ps refer to in your example?